# Robust se. (vcovHC) to be shown with texreg in R

Tags: r, latex, regression, texreg

I am doing some regressions with the plm package, then if needed, I also obtain heteroskedasticity consistent coefficients. Below are the commands that I run;

```
   library(plm)
   data("Produc", package = "plm")
   zz <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, 
             data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))

   summary(zz)

   coeftest(zz, vcovHC)
```

My problem starts here. Below is the list of commands to obtain a Latex output with the help of the texreg. How can I integrate the result obtained with the coeftest command into the Latex output?

```
latex_reg <- texreg(list(coeftest_result),
                    scriptsize=TRUE) 


sink(file="/home/heimatlos/R_outputs/reg_jumps.tex", type="output")
```

OS: Debian Squeeze AMD64

R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)

texreg version: 1.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1.17 of texreg can do this. See [bullet point 3 here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=26680&forum_id=4325&group_id=1420).