# Attribute Order

Tags: r, texreg

I do generate robust standard errors with library(sandwich)
e.g.

```
library(sandwich)
cov.xxx <- vcovHC(xxx, type = "HC")
rob.std.err.xxx <- sqrt(diag(cov.xxx))
```

Then I would like to integrate that in a Latex export presenting several models in parallel. That works "well". I use

```
library(texreg)
      texreg(list(x, xx, xxx, xxxx), 
              custom.model.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
              custom.coef.names = c("Constant", 
              "A", "B", "C",  "D",  "E", "F", "G", "H","I", "J",  "K",  "L", 
              "Wrong Sequenced Element",
              "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U",  "V", "W", "X"),
         groups = list("Var1" = 1:5, 
                       "Var2" = 6:14, 
                       "Var3" = 15:19, "Var4" = 20:25),
         sideways = T,
         single.row = T, 
        override.se = list(c(0.1,0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
                           c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1,
                             0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
                           c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1,
                             0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
                             0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
                           **rob.std.err.xxx   #values from robust regression**
                  ), 
         caption= "zzz", 
         return.string = TRUE, use.packages = FALSE , booktabs = TRUE, dcolumn = TRUE, digits = 3,
            file =  paste0(tablesdir, "xxxx.tex"))
```

However the order of attributes in rob.std.err.xxx does not correspond to my LM model. And I cannot figure out how to alter the SE override properly. If anybody can advise on the same procedure on p-values that would be very much appreciated!

All I would need is to alter the sequence in the rob.std.err.xxx and then export it into my target structure indicated above.

This question refers mainly to a texreg "issue". But as mentioned in the comment a solution exists.

Thanks in advance for any support.

Comment: Solved - SORRY for the very similar entry the following link solves the issue - though the order of attributes question would add flexibility to texreg without need to add further functionality - I guess -  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789303/robust-se-vcovhc-to-be-shown-with-texreg-in-r)